UV Scaling and Mesh Boundary Alignment in Fabric.js and Three.js
I’m currently working on a project using Fabric.js and Three.js, and I have a few questions:
UV Scaling (Pixel-Perfect): What steps should I follow to scale UV maps correctly in Fabric.js and ensure they remain pixel-perfect when transferring them to Three.js? How can I ensure that the UVs are properly matched and scaled?
Drawing Mesh Boundaries: What method can I use to accurately draw the boundaries of a mesh whose UV map I've extracted on Fabric.js or a canvas? Specifically, I want to place images on top of the mesh correctly after determining these boundaries.
yoycoluvmapboundaries
Any guidance or suggestions on resources would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I tried scaling the UV maps in Fabric.js and then mapping them onto a mesh in Three.js. I expected the UVs to match perfectly with the texture on the mesh, maintaining pixel-perfect accuracy. However, the UVs were slightly off, causing the texture to appear distorted. Additionally, when attempting to draw the mesh boundaries on the canvas, the images did not align correctly with the boundaries.
